# Can R create quotation marks around strings in a dataframe? Needed for file formatting

Tags: r, formatting, quotes

I am trying to transform data I currently have into another format for use by a particular program.

I am building a data frame taking select variables from my input file to be exported in the format below.

My labels are stored as columns in a dataframe called xFiltered

`xFiltered [1] 500 500  25 100  50  50   0 500 500 500 100`

Is there a method I can use to change these values as strings with the quotation marks as part of the string printed e.g "500","500" etc ?

I will then add these to an object that will form a column of my new data frame

`col5<- c(xfiltered_with_quotes,rest_of_col)`

Example format (except "A D" ="500")

```
node [id 1 label "A D"]
node [id 2 label "A"]
node [id 3 label "Abe F G"]
node [id 4 label "Abe B"]
node [id 5 label "A B C"]
node [id 6 label "Abe Bob C"]
edge [ source 0 target 1 label "2"]
edge [ source 0 target 2 label "1"]
edge [ source 1 target 2 label "1"]
edge [ source 2 target 3 label "1"]
edge [ source 2 target 4 label "1"]
edge [ source 2 target 5 label "1"]
edge [ source 2 target 6 label "1"]
edge [ source 4 target 5 label "2"]
edge [ source 4 target 6 label "2.1"]
edge [ source 5 target 6 label "3"]
]`
```

Comment: I think you want `dQuote`

Comment: Does `as.character(xFiltered)` help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could just  `paste` the quotes on:

```r
xFiltered <- c(500, 500 , 25, 100, 50, 50, 0, 500, 500, 500, 100)

xFiltered_with_quotes <- paste0("\"", xFiltered, "\"")

cat(xFiltered_with_quotes, sep = "\n")
#> "500"
#> "500"
#> "25"
#> "100"
#> "50"
#> "50"
#> "0"
#> "500"
#> "500"
#> "500"
#> "100"
```

and

```
cat(paste0("[label ", xFiltered_with_quotes, "]\n"), sep = "")
#> [label "500"]
#> [label "500"]
#> [label "25"]
#> [label "100"]
#> [label "50"]
#> [label "50"]
#> [label "0"]
#> [label "500"]
#> [label "500"]
#> [label "500"]
#> [label "100"]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>